# Adding to sharepoint 2010 list programatically

Tags: vb.net, list, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to create a new item in a sharepoint list. Not getting any error messages but the item does not appear in the list.

Here is my code:

```
 'Declare and initialize Lists Web service.
        Dim listService As New Lists()

        'Authenticate 
        listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

        'Set the Url property of the service for the path to a subsite.
        listService.Url = "http://site/subsite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"

        'Get Name attribute values (GUIDs) for list and view. 
        Dim ndListView As System.Xml.XmlNode = listService.GetListAndView(listguid, "")
        Dim strListID As String = ndListView.ChildNodes(0).Attributes("Name").Value
        Dim strViewID As String = ndListView.ChildNodes(1).Attributes("Name").Value

        'Create an XmlDocument object and construct a Batch element and its 
        'attributes. Empty string as view means use the default view. 
        Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
        Dim batchElement As System.Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("Batch")
        batchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue")
        batchElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1")
        batchElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", strViewID)

        'Specify methods for the batch post using CAML.
        'Command id 1 = new
        batchElement.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
                 "<Field Name='Title'>test</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='AssignedTo'>Phil</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Status'>Active</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Priority'>Low</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Comment'>test</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Category'>test</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='DueDate'>9/27/2011 12:00 AM</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='RelatedIssues'></Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='V3Comments'>test</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='NameAndSurname'>test test</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='StudentNo'>209203003</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Account'>accounts</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Author'>Phil</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Complaints'>Complaints</Field>" +
                 "<Field Name='Edited'>Phil</Field></Method>"
        Try
            listService.UpdateListItems(strListID, batchElement)
            LabelStatus.Text = "Call Escalated to sharepoint, ok."
        Catch ex As Exception
            LabelStatus.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong

Cheers,
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

First, try adding:

```
  <Field Name='ID'>New</Field>
```

Also, I would suggest removing other fields, except for Title. And then start adding them back in as you have success. There are two reasons:

1. you want to make sure that your field names are correct
2. non-value types like users or lookups (all those Phils, for example) might need to be formatted in the `ID;#Name` style rather than simple text.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharePoint list programmatically in C#.

Add lookup field for our newly created list.

This is a sample code.

```
public void createList()
{
     // choose your site
   SPSite site = new SPSite("http://merdev-moss:5050");
   SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
   SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
     // create new Generic list called "My List"
   lists.Add("My List", "My list Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList); 
   SPList newList = web.Lists["My List"];

 }
```

or try to use this link 
http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-list-programatically-in_30.html